# How do I add a class to a directive?

Tags: angularjs

given:

`<span my-directive></span>` or
`<my-directive></my-directive>`

I'd like to add a style to this directive with something like:

```
.my-directive{
    color:red;
}
```

or

```
my-directive{
    color:red;
}
```

I've seen it done some places but I can't find the official documentation. The way you specify the CSS seems to change depending on if 'require' is A,E, or both. I currently have my directive set to AE, and use it like A, but neither css style is being picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do like this?:

```
<span class="my-directive" my-directive></span>
```

Comment: Yes that works, but then I'd have to add that class to each instance of my directive across all my files. Is there no better way?

Comment: You can add in `link` function like this: `link: function(scope, element, attrs){ element.addClass('my-directive'); }`

Comment: Ahh I see, that's probably how the examples I saw worked. It's neat since the directive name is unlikely to be used as a class name for other elements.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid adding the class in the directive since it would've been hidden from the HTML and confused people, but if it's the same name as the directive and accepted as convention I can see how useful this is.

Comment: If you worry about that you can pass class name as a parameter, for example: `my-directive-class="my-directive"` and then in js: `element.addClass(attrs.myDirectiveClass)`